# VSTO Excel AddIn Using Enterprise Library Swallowing Exceptions

Tags: excel, vsto, enterprise-library

I have a VSTO Excel add-in created using VS2010, and I am using exception handling from Enterprise Library 5.0.  It works fine in development, but when I deploy using click once, errors are getting swallowed up by Enterprise Library.  I suspect enterprise library is not getting called at all, because I did this:

```cs
try {
   //..
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlMousePointer.xlDefault;
    MessageBox.Show("handle error '" + ex.Message + "' with enterprise Policy");
    exManager.HandleException(ex, "Policy");
}
```

And I get the dialog box, but no error gets logged or displayed or re-thrown.

Does anyone know why the enterprise libraries would fail to load?  I checked, and they are strong signed.

Comment: Since Office eats exceptions it's possible that `exManager.HandleException` is itself throwing an exception. To see these exceptions read the last section on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003(v=vs.80).aspx). Also check out this [VSTO Troubleshooter](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vstotroubleshooter).

Answer (score 0):

this could be due to something wrong in logger configuration, try Debugger.Break and step into exManager.HandleException call if this is not possible try to pop up messagebox inside exManager.Handleexception and check parameter values within

Answer (score 0):

Keith was right, it seems Excel swallows VSTO errors by default. I had to set the environment variable `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` to 0.

Comment: That's great to hear. If you figure out how to get the Enterprise Library working then please post your solution here as an answer.